# Long Range - High Frequency or Low Frequency

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, radio-frequency

I have a confusion regarding which signal covers more distance - high frequency signal or low frequency signal?

My understanding - high frequency signal has high energy. So, it has the energy to cover more distance.

My confusion - the light from the Sun is usually composed of longer wavelengths and not shorter wavelengths. Since, the longer wavelengths covers more distance without attenuation, does low frequency signal have long range?

Comment: Are you asking about communication in space it on the Earth?

Comment: I am asking in General. What is the difference between what's happening in Earth and outer space?

Comment: The difference is the Earth's atmosphere!

Comment: Yes, could you please provide an answer too

Answer (score 1):

Radio waves and microwaves are used for long range communication. Micro waves are used for the satellites which are in distant orbits and radio waves are used for low orbital satellites. They are generally regarded as low frequency waves. The low frequency waves are used for such communication because they scatter less in atmosphere as compared to high frequency waves (see [Rayleigh Scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering)) and have low ability to ionise the gases of atmosphere.

Comment: In case of communication using RF, which covers long range, High frequency or Low frequency?

Comment: RF is the radio frequency, so it is low frequency range.